# The 'Is Desired Intent' is returning a wrong value in Power Automate LUIS connector

Tags: azure-language-understanding, power-automate

I am using the "Get Prediction" connector for LUIS in Power Automate. It seems that even though my desired intent has a high score (90+%) and is the highest scoring intent, the "Is Desired Intent" returns false when it should return true. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with where you're doing this testing. Can you provide some additional details? It seems that your reference intent has + instead of spaces, which is making them not match.

Comment: I am doing this within Power Automate using the "Get Prediction". For desired intent I simply chose from the dropdown the intent that I had created. The scores are accurate, but the false/true statements are wrong.